# Conditions for weak convergence of covariance matrix derivatives

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence

I am considering a model that includes a covariance matrix which is a function of model's parameters:
$$
\mathbf \Sigma = \Sigma(\mathbf \theta),
$$
where $\mathbf \theta$ is $p$-dimensional, $\mathbf \Sigma$ is $d \times d$ and $d \geq p$.

I know that for every $\mathbf \theta$, $\mathbf \Sigma(\mathbf \theta)$ is converging in probability to zero. I would like to know under which conditions this implies:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf \Sigma(\mathbf \theta)}{\partial \mathbf \theta_k} \overset{p}{\to} \mathbf 0, \;\;\; \forall \, k
$$
Do I need to assume uniform convergence of $\frac{\partial \mathbf \Sigma(\mathbf \theta)}{\partial \mathbf \theta_k}$? 
Thank you for any suggestion/pointer!

Comment: You need to be more specific. The meaning of $
\frac{\partial \mathbf \Sigma(\mathbf \theta)}{\partial \mathbf \theta_k} \overset{p}{\to} \mathbf{0}
$ is not clear. You have a matrix-valued random function, you want to it to converge in probability to the zero matrix uniformly, or pointwise, or what...? over the parameter space.